# Enqueue JS + CSS via a child theme functions.php file?

Tags: functions

The below works great in loading a Javascript File into my theme (via a child theme)...

```
function my_scripts_method() {
        if ( is_page_template('templates/page-alert-amber.php')):
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'bootstrap js',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/hellojs.js',
            array( 'jquery' )
        );
        endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

My question is - how do I also include a style sheet? I thought the below would work but it doesn't...

```
function my_scripts_method() {
        if ( is_page_template('templates/page-alert-amber.php')):
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'bootstrap js',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/hellojs.js',
            array('jquery')
        );
            wp_enqueue_style(
            'bootstrap css',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/hello.css',
            array()
        endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the dependency:

```
array( '' )
```

That's setting your stylesheet to have a dependency on a stylesheet whose name is an empty string. If you want to say that there's no dependency you need to use an empty *array*:

```
array()
```

Also, your second bit of code is missing an `endif`, which will cause a fatal error.

Comment: thanks but still no joy...I added the endif and your recommendation but it just crashes the site. There is something else missing here....

Comment: ^ i amended the code pls see my original question which I have edited above

Comment: Now you're missing the closing `);` from `wp_enqueue_style()`...